# string initializing as NULL in C++

Tags: c++, string, null

```
string a=NULL;
```

it gives error. Why and how can I initialize string as NULL?

but when I write

```
string a="foo";
```

this it works fine.

Comment: try to use pointer, you can assign `NULL` to it, but dont forget to use properly `new` and `delete`

Comment: @Borgleader: What's wrong with `string a;`?

Comment: @sbi: Nothing, in fact it's probably better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually to get an empty `std::string`, you just write

```
std::string a;
```

`std::string`'s default constructor will give you an empty string without further prompting.

As an aside, using NULL in C++ is generally discouraged, the recommendation would be to either use 0 (which NULL tends to be defined to anyway) or if you have a modern enough compiler, `nullptr`.

Comment: `nullptr` will be UB, as it will try to construct a `std::string` from a null pointer, which is not allowed by the Standard.

Comment: @DeadMG I think "as an aside" means it doesn't apply to this situation.

Comment: As an aside, I don't see how using `NULL` is discouraged in pre-`nullptr` C++... in practice it's the same as `0` (it's guaranteed to be defined as 0), and it makes more clear that we are talking about pointers.

Comment: @MatteoItalia `foo(NULL)` will it call `foo(char*)` or `foo(int)`? You'd say `foo(char*)` because `NULL` is used for pointers, but it's actually calling `foo(int)`. Clear code is important. Don't ever use `NULL` in C++.

Comment: @Zoidberg'--: no, I'd say `foo(int)` because I *know* that `NULL` is plain zero. But if I make the mistake and later someone else notices that the wrong overload is called he can immediately understand what I meant and add the relevant cast (otherwise he would have to ask me if I meant "integer zero" or "pointer zero"). I agree that `NULL` is a botch - `nullptr` was introduced for a reason, but I feel it's better than using 0 also for pointers. Anyway, all this is both non relevant to the question (I'm sorry for derailing it) and non relevant in general now that `nullptr` solves this problem.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between *null* and *empty string* (an empty string is still a valid string). If you want a "nullable" object (something that can hold *at most* one object of a certain type), you can use [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html):

```
boost::optional<std::string> str; // str is *nothing* (i.e. there is no string)
str = "Hello, world!"; // str is "Hello, world!"
str = ""; // str is "" (i.e. empty string)
```

Answer (score -2):

Let's break down what you are in fact doing:

```
string a=NULL;
```

First you execute `string a`. This creates a new object on the stack, with default value (an empty string). Then you execute `a=NULL`, which calls the assignment function of the string class. But what is `NULL`? `NULL` in C++ is macro expanded into just `0`. So you are attepting to assign an integer to a `string` variable, which of course is not possible.

```
string a="abc"
```

works, because you want to assign a char array, and the `string` class has the assignment operator method overloaded for char arrays, but not for integers. That's why `NULL` doesn't work and "abc" works.

Comment: In C, `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)` but in C++ its just `0`.

Comment: Note the typecast ```(void*)0``` - which means a pointer to 0; not am integer representation of 0. In C++ I think it largely depends on the compiler.

Comment: No, it is just zero. There are plenty of other wrongs in this answer.

Comment: @Timo I edited the question, but I still claim that a pointer is an integer (or long). Otherwise you would not be able to perform pointer arithmetics on it.

Comment: `std::string a = NULL;` is an initialization, not an assignment. `operator=` isn't called (or at least not directly, depending on the implementation).

Comment: @DeadMg please enlighten me.

Comment: "abc" is also an "integer" (pointer to ROM address where "abc" is)

Comment: @Zaffy no. It's an array of chars. It decays to a pointer, and how that pointer is stored (if it is stored at all) is implementation-defined. It may be a floating point number on crazy architectures.

Comment: @JakubZaverka, a pointer is convertible to an numerical value like int or long, but it is a distinct type. That's a big difference.